# Responsive Web Development-CSS -mobile slider height

Tags: css

I am trying to get my slider on my website to adjust to a different height in a mobile screen but didn't get it to work properly.

The website that i am trying to work on is www.msstoreway.com.  After having added the css-code below, i could get the desktop/laptop screen to adjust but on a mobile screen the slider height wont change at all. Can you please advise what i am doing wrong and how to get the height to increase in a mobile screen only.Thanks. See my CSS-Codes that i have added.
regards

Mark

```
    /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
     @media only screen 
     and (max-width : 320px) {
     /* Styles */
    #slider .rslides, #slider .rslides li { height: 250px; max-height: 
    250px; }
    #slider .rslides img { height: 100%; max-height: 250px; }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using for the slider is scaling the height/width as inline styles which is overriding your css styles.

You are able to add the !important tag which will then override the inline styles, but do note you will lose the aspect ratio scaling that the js plugin is implementing.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 500px) { 
    .rslides { height: 250px !important; } 
    .rslides img { height: 250px !important; } 
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but still no luck. See the codes below

Comment: @media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
 
.rslides  {
    height: 250px !important;
}

.rslides img {
    height: 250px !important;
}    
}

Comment: The media query is set to only take affect up to width of 320px, most mobile devices now are larger than that, I believe the iPhone 6 is around 375px. You may have to tweak it to settle on a width you require. But for testing purposes you could set it to around 500px to be certain to cover the mobile devices on the market at the moment (portrait width that is). Have updated the answer to include the media query

Comment: Thanks Ian, It works at 500px. See my code       @media only screen and (max-width:500px){ .rislides{height:250px !important;} .rslides img{height:250px !important;} }